# App fails only while running under samsung galaxy s3

Tags: android, galaxy

What seems to be the reason for crushing on every SGS3 device I'm running my app on ?
This is the only device (with 4.1.2 OS ver.) that fails to run.
I tried: LG optimus one + black, N4 , HTC HD2, SGS 1+2.. and so on...

At the Manifest file, I did:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

Those are the most relevant lines reg. the Manifest.xml (for my problem).

onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to MapView
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
        tvLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
        mapView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        // Setting Zoom Controls on MapView
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(false);

        ImageButton settings = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        settings.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button helpme = (Button)findViewById(R.id.helpMeButton);    //find Button and gives a name: 'help'
        ToggleButton mapExchangeToggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.mapExchangeToggleButton);    
        helpme.setOnClickListener(this);    //register Button as an OnClicklistener
        mapExchangeToggleButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
```

onResume method:

```
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        phoneNumber = pre.getString("phone","" );
    }
```

LogCat is:

```
03-05 20:39:49.910: D/dalvikvm(27589): GC_CONCURRENT freed 173K, 9% free 12425K/13511K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 18ms
03-05 20:39:49.910: D/dalvikvm(27589): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
03-05 20:39:49.910: W/CursorWrapperInner(27589): Cursor finalized without prior close()
03-05 20:39:49.965: D/dalvikvm(27589): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 8% free 12814K/13895K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
03-05 20:39:49.990: W/System.err(27589): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:122)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-05 20:39:49.995: W/System.err(27589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-05 20:39:50.000: W/System.err(27589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 20:39:50.000: D/AndroidRuntime(27589): Shutting down VM
03-05 20:39:50.000: W/dalvikvm(27589): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419242a0)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap/in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:128)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationingooglemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-05 20:39:50.000: E/AndroidRuntime(27589):    ... 11 more
```

onLocationChanged():

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();


         );

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

        tvLocation.setText("Street Address: " +  address+ "\nCity: "+city +"\nCountry: " +country);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1E6), (int)(longitude*1E6));

        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo(point);

        mapController.setZoom(15);

        mapView.invalidate();

        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cur_position);

        CurrentLocationOverlay currentLocationOverlay = new CurrentLocationOverlay(drawable);

        OverlayItem currentLocation = new OverlayItem(point, "Current Location", "Latitude : " + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

        currentLocationOverlay.addOverlay(currentLocation);

        mapOverlays.clear();

        mapOverlays.add(currentLocationOverlay);        

    }
```

Comment: actually you missed the most relevent lines of you problem... show you logcat output with the problem and please describe it more then just "problem".

Comment: I edit my message... actually I installed the apk on every device I ran it on...(including SGS3), but only on SGS3 it fails...

Comment: I understood that but what is logcat output... when you experiences you problem?

Comment: Still we need logcat crash logs to check it out.

Comment: You haven't given us the slightest clue of what your app is or does, only that there's a problem. How are we to know what's wrong?

Comment: It's a Google map activity that does very basic things but it does run great on every device but SGS3... It just fails before it runs, and says that the app crushed with an Ok button only.

Comment: Edit your question with 1) logcat output or stack trace, and 2) relevant code. Since it fails on startup, `onCreate()` and `onResume()` would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Adam, No one will help you here if you don't want to help yourself. It's impossible to even have a clue for the problem when there is not description and a decent peace of trace view.

Comment: I edited my msg. damn luck, I failed to run eclipse now... is there any clue with the extensive info of mine ? thx !!

Comment: Which is line 128 there? So many things could be null.

Comment: address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

Comment: Looks like `addresses` is null. From the docs for [Geocoder:getFromLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation): Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

Comment: But the problem occurs only under SGS3 devices... what seems to be a good solution in that case ?

Comment: @Adam : **what seems to be a good solution in that case ?** Check to make sure that `addresses` isn't null or empty before trying to use it.

Comment: Can u write down the lines that should wrap those lines in order to make it run ? thx !

Comment: I just don't have any clue how to implement this solution...

Answer (score 0):

You're catching and printing:

```
java.io.IOException: Service not Available
```

which means that addresses never gets set and is null:

```
List<Address> addresses = null;
```

so you're likely getting the NullPointerException when you try to access items in that list:

```
address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
```

Looks like android.location.Geocoder isn't available on that specific device. I'd check things like permissions, and that the GPS is turned on/enabled.